# JSON in Jvector Map How to resolve error, TypeError: jvm.WorldMap is not a constructor

Tags: json, jvectormap

In the JVectorMap I want to add the Markers from JSON. [I found an idea here on Github](https://gist.github.com/Szeremeta/5772456).

This is the code I am using:

```
    $.getJSON('/Ajax/Dealers.json', function (data) {

            var map = new jvm.WorldMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            container: $('#world-map'),
             markerStyle: {
                 initial: {
                     fill: '#4087bd',
                     stroke: '#28456f'
                 }
             },
             series: {
                 regions: [{
                     attribute: 'fill'
                 }]
             },
        markers: data
        });
        map.series.regions[0].setValues(customColors);
    });
```

But the problem is I am getting error.

```
TypeError: jvm.WorldMap is not a constructor
```

On this line:

```
 var map = new jvm.WorldMap({
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to include library file or its not in correct location. Include this library file and then try
http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js

Comment: no I guess its included correctly because I can see the map if I don't use JSON.